# It is possible to call a SAP function module in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I cannot use SAP .NET Connector (sapnco.dll) and I didn't found another connector for Xamarin and SAP so my problem is how to call a SAP function from Xamarin.Forms project or maybe there is a better way to retrieve returned table from SAP function module?

I already made a ConsoleApp (.Net Framework) with SAP .NET Connector (NCo) like [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/connect-to-sap-using-c-sharp/) and now I want to make something similar (or not) in a Xamarin.Forms project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used the SAP connector, but from a google search it looks like the SAP .Net connector is a full-framework library, no .netstandard version available.  So unfortunately using it from a Xamarin.Forms project will never work.

In that case, your best bet would be to create a ASP.Net rest-service(.net full-framework) as a intermediary layer between your xamarin app and SAP backend.

Good luck :)